# Django Generic Views disabling fields

Tags: django, django-forms

One Modelform consist two field which is not inserting from front end, but the data is setting in coding level. One is Case No filed and the value updating from sequence and second is a foreign key field mapped to user for log purposes.

```
self.fields['last_modifieduser'].queryset = Profile.objects.filter(user=profile.user,widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

I made the two fields read only and disabled respectively. 
Whenever doing form validation there two fields getting error.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Please show the complete view.

Answer (score 0):

Error in syntax

change code

```
self.fields['last_modifieduser'].queryset = Profile.objects.filter(user=profile.user,widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

to

```
self.fields['last_modifieduser'].queryset = Profile.objects.filter(user=profile.user)
self.fields['last_modifieduser'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

Not tested. But, it will work.

Comment: I did the same, but due to the filed is hidden in the form select drop down the option value which i setted is not selecting. so form.error is getting effected.